Github Actions with more than 1 deploy
I have a github actions workflow that in there I need to do 4 deploys, but all of then are in different folders. So I need that when some changes are made in an unique repository, it just makes deploy on this depository also.
deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Authenticate to Google Cloud
      uses: google-github-actions/auth@v1
      with:
        credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_DEPLOY_KEY }}

    - name: Set up Google Cloud SDK
      uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v1
      with:
        project_id: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}
        install_components: 'beta'

    - name: Deploy Function 1
(deploy it just if any changes are made in ./Function1 repository)
      run: ...

    - name: Deploy Function 2
(deploy it just if any changes are made in ./Function2 repository)
      run: ...
          
    - name: Deploy Function 3
(deploy it just if any changes are made in ./Function3 repository)
      run: ...

    - name: Deploy Function 4
(deploy it just if any changes are made in ./Function4 repository)
      run: ...

I tried using:
if: contains(github.event.head_commit.message, './Function1')
but nothing happens.
Hope you could understand and help me! Thanks!

Do you mean "directory" instead of "repository", when you write "changes are made in ./FunctionX repository"?

I'm asking because triggers for Actions are always specific to a repository; you can't have a single workflow be triggered by events in multiple repositories.

some days ago, I used multiple deploy like this. In my case I also make dependent on each other..
name: SSH Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Setup SSH
      uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.3
      with:
        ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        
    - name: SSH into server 1
      run: |
        <commands>

  deploy2:
    needs: deploy1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Setup SSH
      uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.3
      with:
        ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

    - name: SSH into server 2
      run: |
        <commands>


You could use reusable workflow files. The following should give you an idea (of course you have to adapt it to your actual build steps).
First create a workflow file, e.g. .github/workflows/wf-deploy-function.yml:
name: My Deploy Workflow
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      project-file:
        required: true
        type: string
      project-folder:
        required: true
        type: string
    secrets:      
      gcp_sa_deploy_key:
        required: true
      gcp_project_id:
        required: true
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        name: Checkout the code
      - name: Authenticate to Google Cloud
        uses: google-github-actions/auth@v1
        with:
          credentials_json: ${{ secrets.gcp_sa_deploy_key }}
      - name: Set up Google Cloud SDK
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v1
        with:
          project_id: ${{ secrets.gcp_project_id }}
          install_components: 'beta'
      - name: Deploy Function
        run: ... (use your inputs here, e.g. ${{ github.workspace }}\${{ inputs.project-folder }} )

Now create a yml file for each of your Function apps.
E.g. .github/workflows/DeployFunction1.yml
name: Deploy Function 1
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'Function1/**'
      - 'MyCommonCode/**'
jobs:
  deploy-function:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/wf-deploy-function.yml
    with:
      project-file: 'Function1/myProjectFile'
      project-folder: 'Function1'
    secrets:
      gcp_sa_deploy_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_DEPLOY_KEY }}
      gcp_project_id: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}

E.g. .github/workflows/DeployFunction2.yml
name: Deploy Function 2
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'Function2/**'
      - 'MyCommonCode/**'
jobs:
  deploy-function:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/wf-deploy-function.yml
    with:
      project-file: 'Function2/myProjectFile'
      project-folder: 'Function2'
    secrets:
      gcp_sa_deploy_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_DEPLOY_KEY }}
      gcp_project_id: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}

For each of these files you can define the paths on which a change will trigger the workflow.
